# Reading binary data from TCP clients using Netty

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I'm trying  get byte data from TCP client applications. Following the documentation of Netty project I found this code and use it in my system:

```
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
      b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
  
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                   ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                   p.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1048576, 0, 4, 0, 4));
                   p.addLast("bytesDecoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());
                   p.addLast(new ServerHandler());
                            
                   }
        });
```

But in my `ServerHandler` class I'm unable to find and call the method:

```
void channelRead (ChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] bytes){}
```

instead of the typical:

```
void channelRead (ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do cast...

```
void channelRead (ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){
    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) msg;
}
```

Comment: Ok,thank you, but for what reason I need add to the pipeline the handlers `p.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1048576, 0, 4, 0, 4));` and 
`p.addLast("bytesDecoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());`?? If is just do a cast?

Comment: because otherwise you will not receive a byte[] but a ByteBuffer

Comment: Thanks for you answer and for develop Netty is an amazing framework :)